# Нужна ли запятая после "знаю" в данном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая после "знаю" в данном предложении?
*Уж не знаю, верить ли нашему учителю математики.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:

***Уж не знаю**, верить **ли** нашему учителю математики.*

Это СПП с придаточным **изъяснительным**, частица ***ЛИ*** использована в значении **подчинительного** союза. Запятая ставится перед **придаточным** предложением.